# Proxy server not working with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to add proxy with chrome and when I ran one of my previous scripts I got an error.

```
PROXY = "139.59.207.66:3128"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://www.whatsmyip.org/")
```

[image: error]

I am unable to figure out the reason for this error. Please guide me about it.